# Fetching "gnome-system-monitor" data in terminal

Tags: linux, debian, system-monitoring

Is there any way to retrive the "gnome-system-monitor" data in the terminal, including the cpu+memory etc. usage. Geting the list under the "Processes" of the application is the major requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use top if you want live results. Else you can use ps -eF

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top` or a colorful version with some more features: `htop`